# How to svn import a directory that contains subdirectories already with .svn folders?

Tags: svn, import, repository, svnignore

I've been using svn for a while, I have everything inside a /work directory but have mixed versioned directories with non-versioned, and the local directory structure does not mirror that of the repository (long story, but basically each 'project' was imported individually).  Now I want to just have everything under one big 'work' umbrella so that committing and adding projects is easier and faster.

Right now the only way I know how to do it is to create a temp directory and put everything in there that is not currently under version control, then svn export all the others (individually), then svn import the whole thing, and finally, check it out into the new /work umbrella.

The problem is that it seems like an error prone method, and I was wondering if there is an easier way (like svn import but ignoring the .svn folders, or something like that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursively remove the `.svn` directories before copying them in place, and then `svn add ...` them and check them in.

Answer (score 0):

If you use TortoiseSVN theres is an option called Export, then you must select the target directory and voilá, your project is clean.
Or you can use commands:
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re10.html